# ckfinder integration with ckeditor

Tags: php, ckeditor

This is my integration code:

```
 My extranet is in root/include/ckeditor and root/include/ckfinder

$baseUrl = 'https://extranet.com/crm/include/;
$baseUrl = '/userfiles/';

$baseDir = '/crm/include/userfiles/;
```

I am trying to do the configuration thats all. 
I am trying to integrated with ckeditor but i am getting all sorts of error. Can anyone tell me where iam doing wrong.

```
It was not possible to properly load the XML response from the web server.
    XML Parsing Error: junk after document element Location: https://extranet.zeald.com/crm_snapshot/include/ckfinder/ckfinder.html?CKEditor=message&CKEditorFuncNum=2&langCode=en Line Number 2, Column 1:Parse error: parse error, unexpected T_STRING, expecting T_OLD_FUNCTION or T_FUNCTION or T_VAR or '}' in /mnt/clusternfs2/extranet/crm_snapshot/include/ckfinder/core/connector/php/php4/Utils/Misc.php on line 54
    ^
    Raw response from the server:


    Parse error: parse error, unexpected T_STRING, expecting T_OLD_FUNCTION or T_FUNCTION or T_VAR or '}' in /mnt/clusternfs2/extranet/crm_snapshot/include/ckfinder/core/connector/php/php4/Utils/Misc.php on line 54
```

Edit:
looking into the Misc.php here the code which is giving the error

```
public static function encodeURIComponent($str)
    {
        $revert = array('%21'=>'!', '%2A'=>'*', '%27'=>"'", '%28'=>'(', '%29'=>')');
        return strtr(rawurlencode($str), $revert);
    }
```

I have got php version 4.3.10 running and I read the ckfinder documentation that version2.2.1 is being supported by php4+.

Edit:
I have removed this code and it seems to be working :

```
/*  public static function encodeURIComponent($str)
    {
        $revert = array('%21'=>'!', '%2A'=>'*', '%27'=>"'", '%28'=>'(', '%29'=>')');
        return strtr(rawurlencode($str), $revert);
    } */
```

Is there a way to make this work.

Hope someone can help me out.

Comment: Post code so people can help you?

Comment: You seem to have a missing closing quote in `$baseDir = '/crm/include/userfiles/;`.

Comment: hi juan even I added the quote still happens